# Assign serial number by unique time in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame as below:

```
dt: 
Time              users
14-10-2016 13:00    a
14-10-2016 13:05    b
14-10-2016 13:05    c
14-10-2016 14:20    a
14-10-2016 14:20    b
14-10-2016 14:20    a
14-10-2016 14:25    d
```

I want to assign serial numbers by unique Time as below:

```
Time              users ID
14-10-2016 13:00    a   1
14-10-2016 13:05    b   2
14-10-2016 13:05    c   2
14-10-2016 14:20    a   3
14-10-2016 14:20    b   3
14-10-2016 14:20    a   3
14-10-2016 14:25    d   4
```

How can i assign serial numbers in ID column?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match`

```
dt[, ID := match(Time, unique(Time))]
```

---

Or with `.GRP` after grouping by 'Time'

```
dt[, ID := .GRP, by = Time]
dt
#               Time users ID
#1: 14-10-2016 13:00     a  1
#2: 14-10-2016 13:05     b  2
#3: 14-10-2016 13:05     c  2
#4: 14-10-2016 14:20     a  3
#5: 14-10-2016 14:20     b  3
#6: 14-10-2016 14:20     a  3
#7: 14-10-2016 14:25     d  4
```